# finite difference estimator of the derivative of the inverse distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, estimation, finite-differences

let $x_1,...,x_n$, $n\geq 3$ be a sample form the distribution $F$. We want to estimate $\frac{dF^{-1}(p)}{dp}$, replacing the distribution function $F$ by empirical distribution function $F_n$, and using a difference operator in place of differential operator.

We can write $F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I(x\geq x_k)$, and, $F_n^{-1}(p)=\inf\{x:F_n(x)\geq p\}.$
Let $i$ be such that $\frac{i-1}{n}\leq p\leq \frac{i}{n}$. Then required estimation

\begin{align}\widehat{\frac{d}{dp}F^{-1}(p)}&=\Delta F_n^{-1}(p)\\
&=\Delta \inf\{x:F_n(x)\geq p\}\\
\end{align}
Consider $F_n(x)\geq p$ for some $x$. The set of such $x$ form an interval $[x_{(i-m)},x_{(i+m)}]$, where $m\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.
Then

$$\widehat{\frac{d}{dp}F^{-1}(p)}=\Delta [x_{(i-m)},x_{(i+m)}] $$
$$\widehat{\frac{d}{dp}F^{-1}(p)}=n\frac{x_{(i+m)}-x_{(i-m)}}{2m}$$

Is it correct way of doing? Kindly help me. Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Is this about _probability distributions_?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, it is

Comment: I changed the tag [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory) to [probability-distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-distributions).